# How to populate drop down list box with certain calendar range values in javascript

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I have 3 drop down list boxes, `year`, `month`, and `day`.

I need to populate values for the last 1095 days from the current date. Currently I'm doing this by running a query in SQL with calendar system table. Is there a way to do it directly in javascript?

The reason I went to SQL is I was not able to associate the 3 drop down boxes for 1095 days from today. For example, say today is Sept 6 2009. If I select 2009 for the `year`, then the `month` drop down should list from Sept, and the `day` drop down should list from 6.

I need the user to have the flexibilty to choose any date from last 1095 days .so  First the user selects 2009 .only Then month drop down box should be populated .and it should only have months from september to decemenber .then after selecting month as september only 1 to 30 should be populated in day drop down box .I m doing this currently by using system date table in sql .

Comment: Hello, have a look here http://jsfiddle.net/gCDXs/ or use [jQueryUI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Comment: This will give me only the old the date .I need the entire range .I need the user to have the flexibilty to choose any date from last 1095 days .so First the user selects 2009 .only Then month drop down box should be populated .and it should only have months from september to decemenber .then after selecting month as september only 1 to 30 should be populated in day drop down box

Answer (score 0):

The code is a bit difficult, but imho the following works well. Made two similar functions, first one is called onload to initialize all three selectboxes, the second one is called when the onchange event occurs:

```js
function init_dates() {

    var now = new Date();
    var newest = [];
    newest[0] = now.getFullYear();
    newest[1] = now.getMonth() + 1;
    newest[2] = now.getDate();

    var old = new Date(now.getTime() - 1095 * 86400 * 1000);
    var oldest = [];
    oldest[0] = old.getFullYear();
    oldest[1] = old.getMonth() + 1;
    oldest[2] = old.getDate();

    // YEARS
    var opt;
    var i = oldest[0];
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    while (i <= newest[0]) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        if (i == newest[0]) {
            opt.selected = 'selected';
        }
        year.appendChild(opt);
        i++;
    }

    // MONTHS
    var minmonth = (year.value == oldest[0]) ? oldest[1] : 1;
    var maxmonth = (year.value == newest[0]) ? newest[1] : 12;
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    while (minmonth <= maxmonth) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = minmonth;
        opt.innerHTML = minmonth;
        month.appendChild(opt);
        minmonth++;
    }

    // DAYS
    var minday = (year.value == oldest[0] && month.value == oldest[1]) ? oldest[2] : 1;
    var maxday = (year.value == newest[0] && month.value == newest[1]) ? newest[2] : 33;
    if (maxday == 33) {
        // find correct maxday
        maxday = 27;
        var d = new Date(year.value, month.value - 1, maxday, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        while (d.getDate() > 1) {
            maxday++;
            d = new Date(year.value, month.value - 1, maxday, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        maxday--;
    }
    var day = document.getElementById('day');
    while (minday <= maxday) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = minday;
        opt.innerHTML = minday;
        day.appendChild(opt);
        minday++;
    }
}

function update_dates() {
    var now = new Date();
    var newest = [];
    newest[0] = now.getFullYear();
    newest[1] = now.getMonth() + 1;
    newest[2] = now.getDate();

    var old = new Date(now.getTime() - 1095 * 86400 * 1000);
    var oldest = [];
    oldest[0] = old.getFullYear();
    oldest[1] = old.getMonth() + 1;
    oldest[2] = old.getDate();

    //selected date in selectboxes
    var year = document.getElementById('year');
    var month = document.getElementById('month');
    var day = document.getElementById('day');
    var sel = new Date(year.value, month.value-1, day.value, 0,0,0,0);
    var selected = [];
    selected[0] = sel.getFullYear();
    selected[1] = sel.getMonth() + 1;
    selected[2] = sel.getDate();
    year.innerHTML = month.innerHTML = day.innerHTML = ''; //clear old list

    // YEARS
    var opt;
    var i = oldest[0];
    while (i <= newest[0]) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = i;
        opt.innerHTML = i;
        if (i == selected[0]) {
            opt.selected = 'selected';
        }
        year.appendChild(opt);
        i++;
    }

    // MONTHS
    var minmonth = (year.value == oldest[0]) ? oldest[1] : 1;
    var maxmonth = (year.value == newest[0]) ? newest[1] : 12;
    while (minmonth <= maxmonth) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = minmonth;
        opt.innerHTML = minmonth;
        if (minmonth== selected[1]) {
            opt.selected = 'selected';
        }
        month.appendChild(opt);
        minmonth++;
    }

    // DAYS
    var minday = (year.value == oldest[0] && month.value == oldest[1]) ? oldest[2] : 1;
    var maxday = (year.value == newest[0] && month.value == newest[1]) ? newest[2] : 33;
    if (maxday == 33) {
        // find correct maxday
        maxday = 27;
        var d = new Date(year.value, month.value - 1, maxday, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        while (d.getDate() > 1) {
            maxday++;
            d = new Date(year.value, month.value - 1, maxday, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        maxday--;
    }
    while (minday <= maxday) {
        opt = document.createElement('option');
        opt.value = minday;
        opt.innerHTML = minday;
        day.appendChild(opt);
        if (minday == selected[2]) {
            opt.selected = 'selected';
        }
        minday++;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gCDXs/1/